# Angular url matcher - match any path starting with

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I use angular2+ router and I'm trying to match any path starting with `/tree` e.g:

`example.com/projects/1/repository/tree/src`
`example.com/projects/1/repository/tree/src/app`
`example.com/projects/1/repository/tree/src/app/core`
and so on.

I tried this approach, but it doesn't work: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#regex-parameters

My router config:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'projects/:id/repository/{tree:.*}',
    component: FilesListComponent
}
```

Everything after `tree` I need to capture as a parameter in the controller, so I can make an API call with it.

Comment: Why do you look for the documentation of angular-ui-router when using another, completely different router: the native angular router? Here's what you need to use: https://angular.io/api/router/Route#matcher

Comment: I am aware of that, however there isn't any useful information in this documentation that can answer my question. So I thought the URL matching might be the same and gave it a try.

Comment: There is. I linked to it. It even contains an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution try this..

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from "@angular/router";
    import { Event as NavigationEvent } from "@angular/router";

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      public url: string;
      constructor(router: Router) {

        router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationEvent): void => {
            this.url = router.url;
            if (this.url.match('/tree/')) {          
              console.log("Matched your Path",this.url);
            }
          }
        );

      }
    }
```

you can change your matching part is here

```
 if(this.url.match('give your matching here')){
       //do something
 }
```

you get the captured value in `this.url` variable.

Its worked perfect. I hope its help.