# Angular 2 routing: match any path with a given prefix

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I need the angular router to match any path that begins with a given prefix to a component. This is my router config.

```
  {
    path: 'posts/:id/:title',
    component: PostDetailsComponent
  }
```

When I navigate to a route like `/posts/1/json-web-token-(jwt)-authentication-with-asp.net-core-2.0` using `router.navigate()` everything works fine but as soon as I try refreshing the page, an error pops up

```
 Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'jwt'
   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'jwt'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1719)
```

I have tried the solution recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48136986/angular-url-matcher-match-any-path-starting-with) but it doesn't seem to work in my specific situation. I have also tried changing my router config to:

```
  {
    path: 'posts/:id/**',
    component: PostDetailsComponent
  }
```

But that just errored out when building. Is there any way I can just match any route beginning with `/posts/:id/`?

Comment: you can do it with child routes to match how you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I stumbled into a solution. I removed any special characters from the `title` and replaced spaces with hyphens. This is how my url generation logic looked:

```
const cleanTitle = title.toLocaleLowerCase()
  .replace(/\s\s+/g, '-') // replace duplicate whitespace with hyphen
  .replace('(', '')
  .replace(')', '');
this.router.navigate([`/posts/${id}/${cleanTitle}`]);
```

after this, the routing config started matching urls like `/posts/1/json-web-token-jwt-authentication-with-asp.net-core-2.0`

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to match *any* routes after a certain prefix, you need to use the *special* '**' *catchAll* in a child route:

```js
{
    path: 'posts',
//or with :id
//  path: 'posts/:id',
    children: [
        {
          path: '**',
          component: PostDetailsComponent
        }
    ]
    
}
```

This will match **all** routes with the *"prefix"* `posts`, such as `posts/8634986/json-in-urls-rockz-or-not`*or* `posts/my/path/is/longer/than/yours`.

However that way you will *lose* a lot of Angular Router's magic: *params* and so on. Furthermore it does of course only work with *valid* (in terms of what the Angular Router deems to be *valid*) URL. To actually access the URL, you will need to use `Router.url`.